# Communication between windows store app and windows phone app with NFC

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, nfc

Is it possible to tap a windows phone to a NFC reader connected to a windows laptop running a windows store app?
what I want to achieve is to send a message from windows phone to windows store app, and trigger a registration action.
any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fully supported through the Windows.Networking.Proximity APIs. However, the problem you may hit is that it's difficult to find desktop/laptops that support NFC proximity. You can easily find NFC readers that can read smart cards and tags, but most of these don't support proximity.

The only USB dongle I've seen that supports proximity is this Sony one, however I've also heard that there are reliability problems with it: http://www.sony.net/Products/felica/business/products/RC-S380.html